# Is there a way to display check list items on the Trello board without specifically having to click on the card?

Tags: trello-cards, trello-boards, trello-lists

Just for specificity's sake, I have a checklist with two items in a card on a list on a board.  When viewing the board, only the card's description is in view, but I'd like to see the individual items on the list.

Is this a current feature and if not, is it possible to implement in the near future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not currently, at the moment you must open the card to see which items have been completed.

Without opening a card you can only see how many items that have been completed across all checklists (eg: 2/9, even if 1 item in a checklist of 4 and another item in a checklist of 5 have been completed).

Comment: I miss that feature too.

Comment: As of 1/31/2016, I don't see anything about the checklist on the front of the card, not even how many items have been completed. Help?

Comment: Ok fwiw it seems like you can get the checklist icon with number of items completed onto the front of your card by 1. add a checklist 2. add a due date 3. now they both show up 4. remove the due date 5. now only the checklist icon shows up, as desired. or maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

We added Power-Up to display checklist at the front of the card.

Show Checklist - https://trello.com/power-ups/5fb7eaf8055b9566a547e0f9

[image]